# Why is the body element overlapping its child element?

Tags: html, css

In this [example](http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/lgFiq), if you change **main div**'s 'left' property to something like **10%**, the body will overlap the element. WHY? It's driving me crazy.

HTML

```
<main>
  <div>
     I'm a block-level element of an unknown height and width, centered vertically within my parent.
  </div>
</main>
```

CSS

```
body {
  background: #f06d06;
  font-size: 80%;
  padding: 20px;
}

main {
  position: relative;
  background: white;
  height: 200px;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}

main div {
      background: black;
      color: white;
      width: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 10%;
      padding: 20px;
      resize: both;
      overflow: auto;
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Body is not overlapping the element, rather the content is getting hidden because of the negative translation.

Comment: because of 'transform' property. please try remove this line; 'transform: translate(-50%, -50%);'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `main div` to show, without being cropped, you need to change the overflow on `main` to `overflow: visible`. Might need more clarification on what you're trying to achieve. :)

Comment: Yes! That's it! I thought it was something to do with z-index or stacking context, but that's not applicable here so I was stumped! I thought overflow: auto provided scroll bars if elements were hidden. It didn't provide them here for some reason.

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help. You can always set `overflow: scroll` if you need it to scroll.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure its the translate you are doing making it go to -40%.

Comment: Yes, but I was looking for why the body was covering the element instead of the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

It's conflicting with the transform property, try this:

```
main div {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  width: 50%;
 /* transform: translate(-50%, -50%);*/
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 10%;
  padding: 20px;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Oh no, I'm not trying to center the div. I get that translate moves the div to left so its on the edge. I just wanted to know why the body OVERLAPPING THE DIV instead of the div OVERLAPPING THE BODY? @monsteronfire solved it. It was the overflow property.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, remove the `overflow:auto` from `main`:

```css
main {
  position: relative;
  background: white;
  height: 200px;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  resize: both;
  /* overflow: auto; */
}
```

Comment: Yes! That's it! I thought it was something to do with z-index or stacking context, but that's not applicable here so I was stumped! I thought overflow: auto provided scroll bars if elements were hidden. It didn't provide them here for some reason.

Comment: Yes ,it not relative to "z-index",I am amazed that you can read my answer,because I am from China.This is my first answer.In fact ,you should read knowledge of  "CSS3 transform" and "position".